# Visualforce Email template recipient type with multiple customized objects. Create customized object

Tags: custom-object, visualforce-component, related-list, custom-controller, vf-email-template

Requirement is to use email template with visual force components, and send an email for each environment the contact is associated to. For example, contactA is associated with env1, env2, and env3. I need to send 3 emails to contactA: with one email for env1, one email for env2, and one email for env3.

```
// Scheduler executes and triggers email sending.
public with sharing class SenderForIncidents Implements Schedulable{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        // Queries prepared template, orgWideEmail, and contactList
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailSendList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Contact c : contactList){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.set...(...);
            emailSendList.add(email);
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(emailSendList, false);
    }
}

// Email template --------------------------------------
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!relatedTo.Name}" 
                         recipientType="Contact" 
                         relatedToType="Environment__c">
     <c:MyController contactEmail="{!recipient.Email__c}"  environmentId="{!relatedTo.Id}" />
</messaging:emailTemplate>

// Visual force component --------------------------------------
<apex:component controller="MyController" access="global">
     <apex:attribute name="contactEmail" type="String" assignTo="{!contactEmail}" />
    <apex:attribute name="environmentId" type="Id" assignTo="{!envId}" />
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!incidents.empty}">
        <apex:repeat value="{!incidents}" var="incident">
             <p>{!incident.fieldA__c}</p>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>

// Controller --------------------------------------
public class MyController {
    public String contactEmail {get; set;}
    public Id envId {get; }
    public void setEnvId(Id envId) { 
        !!!!!!!!! problem here ***************************
        List<Id> envId = [queries based on contactEmail]
        ******* I only need 1 environment for this email, though I have a list of associated environments. but I also need to make sure each env will be covered.

    }

    public List<Case> incidents;
    public List<Case> getIncidents() {
        if (incidents == null) {
            List<Object2> matchedObj2 = [SELECT Case__c FROM Object2 where Environment__c = :envId];

            List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
            for (Object2 obj : matchedObj2) {
                caseIds.add(obj.Case__c);
            }
            incidents = [SELECT .... FROM Case WHERE Id in :caseIds AND ...];
        }
        return incidents;
    }
```

However, during query, I can only find the **list** of environments associated to contact (based on contact email), instead of a single environment. When implementing `setEnvId(){}` in controller, I do not know which environment I should set. Besides setting an environment Id, I need to make sure all env1, env2, env3 are covered.

Stuck for 2 days without feasible solution. Please help to take a look.

Comment: @cropredy Could you please take a look?

Comment: what is the schema that defines the relationship between Contact and Environments? Please use [edit] to amend your question.